# My Python class does not answer right when I call it

Tags: python

I'm having some problems calling my created Python class, let's say I want to create a class for a queue, and I just want it to have the init and some method for me to know it worked:

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self, listIn = []):
        self.lista = listIn

    def show(self):
        return self.lista
```

when I add code such as:

```
y = Queue()
y.__init__()
print(y.show())
```

it works just fine as long as the code stays in the same document. But when I run it from the shell and import it

```
from queue import Queue
```

it works differently, for example; the call print(y) changes from

```
'<__main__.Queue object at ...>'
```

to

```
'<queue.Queue object at ...>'
```

and the `call print(y.show())` changes from `[]` to `'Queue' object has no attribute 'show'`

Why doesn't this work the same way and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python standard library also has a module `queue`, that also has a class `Queue`. The standard library's `queue.Queue` doesn't have a `show()` method. Name your module something else so that you certainly import the correct one.

Also:

1. Don't call `y.__init__()` after making an instance, it's already been done automatically by `y = Queue()`.
2. Don't use [] as a default argument -- all your Queue instances will share the same list. Instead, if you really want to be able to pass in an initial list, do

   ```
   class Queue:
       def __init__(self, listIn=None):
           if listIn is None:
               self.lista = []
           else:
               self.lista = listIn
   ```

Answer (score 1):

a) you don't need to call `y.__init__()`. You already called `__init__` when you did `Queue()`

Now the actual answer. The repr for your object is

```
<MODULE.CLASS object at ADDRESS>
```

When you use it inside the same script MODULE becomes `__main__`, where as importing `Queue` from `queue` will mean that it is `queue.Queue` that you are referencing